# Detectar de qual botão submit foi enviado

Tags: php

Tem alguma forma de detectar no php de qual botão submit foi enviado? Para criar uma função, caso um seja clicado execute uma, caso seja o outro execute a outra função?

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="submit" name="F1" value="atualizar">
  <input type="submit" name="F2" value="deletar">
</form>
```

Comment: E se colocar ambos os botões com mesmo `name`, não bastaria fazer `$_POST['<nome>']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
//algo postado

    if (isset($_POST['F1'])) {
       // atualizar
    } else {
       // deletar
    }

}
```

Com mesmo name dos botões:

```
 <input type="submit" name="qqname" value="atualizar">
 <input type="submit" name="qqname" value="deletar">
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_POST['qqname'] == 'atualizar') {
    // atualizar
}
else if ($_POST['qqname'] == 'deletar') {
    // deletar
}
```

Comment: Ficou mió que o meu.

Comment: Gostei, isso diminui o meu cod.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz como se fosse para um input do tipo checkbox, ficou assim:

`<?php
    if(isset($_POST['F1'])){
        echo 'f1 exite'; 
    }else{ 
        echo 'f1 não existe';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['F2'])){ 
        echo 'f2 existe';
    }else{ 
        echo 'f2 não existe';
    }
?>`